# função contrária de reshape2::melt (desempilhar)

Tags: r, data.frame, reshape

Estou trabalhando com `data.frame` e ele está organizado no formato long. Porém eu gostaria de colocar no formato wide em função de uma variável (`FAT2`) de tal forma que as disposições das colunas ficariam: `AVA`, `FAT1`, `Banana`, `Ingá`, `Gliricídia`, `Pupunha`.

Entretanto, não gostaria de converter em matriz, e depois novamente em `data.frame`. A função `melt` do pacote `reshape2` faz no caso o contrário do que eu preciso, pois ela empilha as variáveis.

dados:

```
dados<-structure(list(AVA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("Março de 2016", 
"Agosto de 2016", "Dezembro de 2016", "Março de 2017", "Agosto de 2017", 
"Fevereiro de 2018", "Abril de 2018", "Agosto de 2018"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), FAT1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Antes", "Após"), class = "factor"), 
    FAT2 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("Banana", "Gliricídia", "Ingá", "Pupunha", 
    "Solteiro"), class = "factor"), LUX = c(39018.33, 38870, 
    40375, 39686.67, 53363.33, 55666.67, 56888.33, 57768.33, 
    5029.33, 4758, 4810.67, 5044.67, 17840.67, 2917.33, 8508.67, 
    9960.67, 3014, 4704.67, 5712, 3815.33, 4683.33, 49213.33, 
    54353.33, 57226.67, 13939.33, 13869.33, 5100.67, 15864, 1809.47, 
    1814.53, 6084.67, 2357.33, 28333.33, 37586.67, 35640, 36833.33, 
    55886.67, 59886.67, 63193.33, 63346.67, 25313.33, 36593.33, 
    24466.67, 38420, 26700, 29106.67, 36746.67, 52300, 25586.67, 
    13106.67, 2782.67, 15677.33, 18310.67, 2864.67, 1893.13, 
    2330, 5256.67, 5313.33, 3916, 5219.33, 5176.67, 6183.33, 
    2959.33, 3823.33, 803.93, 1815.87, 1629.93, 1886.47, 7705.33, 
    2350, 2322.6, 1715.8, 25313.33, 23700, 38420, 28253.33, 26700, 
    11562.67, 49326.67, 52300, 9258, 7078, 6374, 7147, 6435, 
    8366, 9639, 129220, 3481, 1973.8, 4097, 3584, 4189, 1573, 
    3312, 2488, 2886, 2908, 4489, 4047, 4641, 3429, 3434, 4903, 
    4341, 4352, 5019, 8046, 4060, 4552, 5445, 7159, 7870, 4004, 
    5660, 9790, 8772, 6728, 129010, 128520, 27106.67, 19360, 
    28766.67, 25513.33, 29606.67, 30206.67, 21666.67, 34660, 
    15920, 18108.67, 6322, 2402.67, 19686.67, 28853.33, 2898, 
    3403.33, 2437.33, 4086, 25520, 22993.33, 2664, 4850, 3688, 
    3084.67, 22528.67, 4182, 24286.67, 4442.67, 29561.54, 29606.67, 
    28740, 34120, 16304.67, 12944.67, 25466.67, 25513.33, 26006.67, 
    30836.36, 35130, 34645.45, 15926.67, 16664, 24580, 15746, 
    15780.67, 37533.33, 63600, 21560, 12336, 15016.67, 8820.67, 9112, 29880, 35580, 31173.33, 21893.33, 5828, 8477.33, 8122.67, 
    13715.33, 7430, 14023.33, 13144.67, 6759.33, 5126.67, 7038.67, 
    13430.67, 13701.33, 8657.33, 14273.33, 21368, 18332, 16500, 
    16000, 14870.67, 14990.67, 13547.33, 14310, 14806.67, 13180, 
    39786.67, 58420, 56646.67, 59280, 60213.33, 60633.33, 61533.33, 
    64240, 46886.67, 55386.67, 9316, 43553.33, 5883.33, 5913.33, 
    39906.67, 13561.33, 29660, 11585.33, 25340, 8721.33, 57513.33, 
    58613.33, 5214, 60060, 9409.33, 36626.67, 22033.33, 7980.67, 
    7192, 5508, 57680, 9765.33, 39020, 35806.67, 56393.33, 50346.67, 
    23554, 54246.67, 63540, 62333.33, 14585, 54200, 55500, 18350, 
    18340, 54100, 58200, 12260, 17285, 15520, 6565, 5650, 34116.67, 
    4145, 27601.33, 3215, 2110, 2425, 4955, 5000, 2955, 3230, 
    9165, 4550, 3310, 6505, 4375, 4635, 4260, 3635, 4205, 3480, 
    10820, 12205, 16245, 13600, 17000, 13425.33, 11295, 11950, 
    4350, 5040, 6060, 16640, 10440, 24000, 29100, 30700, 3280, 
    3150, 2810, 2735, 17050, 20650, 9645, 10050, 4775, 4370, 
    5575, 5340, 3490, 6555, 5060, 5015, 2375, 2320, 4015, 3265, 
    7570, 6380, 28550, 26750, 4100, 3110, 14715, 15260, 4915, 
    4740, 27850, 17625, 3015, 3760, 4460, 4720, 5115, 5655, 6030, 
    9560, 2015, 2070, 2015, 2135, 2320, 2050, 2895, 2855, 2085, 
    2355, 2160, 2000, 2600, 2955, 3050, 3020, 2010, 2030, 2990, 
    2890, 3785, 3880, 4610, 3890, 2165, 2835, 4625, 4650, 4045, 
    4190, 6715, 6340, 4640, 5425, 8295, 16705, 28450, 17340, 
    11920, 16360, 4455, 4690, 4580, 4485, 11455, 10970, 13070, 
    11050, 3080, 3650, 3425, 3225, 9400, 9245, 9250, 7560, 4015, 
    3930, 14690, 15655, 24650, 25050, 10755, 9665, 4560, 2800, 
    6540, 15120, 23650, 24500, 11780, 11835, 14585, 54200, 55500, 
    18350, 18340, 54100, 58200, 12260, 17285, 15520, 6565, 5650, 
    38184, 35550, 19769.33, 10050, 14730, 43700, 7765, 53400, 
    3490, 6555, 9165, 4550, 3310, 6505, 4375, 4635, 4260, 3635, 
    4205, 3480, 10820, 12205, 16245, 13600, 16700, 16920, 11295, 
    11940, 6378.67, 8702, 12030.67, 12763.33, 11382.67, 10196.67, 
    15526.67, 25286.67, 6464.67, 6798.67, 7080.67, 7154, 7233.33, 
    7295.33, 8962, 8216.67, 5050, 5228, 5123.33, 5759.33, 4839.33, 
    5850, 10330.67, 9663.33, 6067.33, 5602.67, 11512, 11443.33, 
    8872, 6894.67, 15792, 17444, 6363.33, 6348, 10490, 10608.67, 
    10612, 10328.67, 20473.33, 21013.33, 12346.67, 11642, 11633.33, 
    10872.67, 11450, 14792.67, 15706.67, 16808.67, 5212, 6328.67, 
    7770.67, 7900.67, 6811.33, 8420.67, 9960, 11131.33, 4928.67, 
    5762, 3576.67, 5667.33, 4864, 8104, 8059.33, 10923.33, 8298.67, 
    7838.67, 7096.67, 7933.33, 8718, 8661.33, 10809.33, 13119.33, 
    11730, 11612.67, 8514.67, 10682, 11146.67, 11176, 16385.33, 
    15394.67, 5042, 5016, 4355.33, 10662.67, 8518.67, 9772, 9260.67, 
    14453.33, 2844, 3033.33, 3482.67, 3040.67, 8392, 8357.33, 
    6963.33, 7312.67, 2083.33, 2644.67, 3127.33, 3185.33, 5400, 
    6658.67, 6665.33, 7681.33, 3954.67, 3862.67, 5732, 6284.67, 
    6444.67, 6130.67, 9072.67, 10302.67, 4456, 4186.67, 9228.67, 
    8806.67, 7652.67, 7651.33, 11231.33, 11864.67, 10765.33, 
    10205.33, 13295.33, 181760, 25786.67, 28353.33, 28133.33, 
    32020, 6081.33, 6643.33, 5420.67, 6404, 9358.67, 9443.33, 
    14206.67, 5926.67, 5401.33, 5755.33, 3053.33, 3208.67, 3636.67, 
    8914, 5722, 2652, 8018, 7822, 8363.33, 6810, 14776, 8667.33, 
    29380, 12555, 10355.33, 8673.33, 13400.67, 13861.33, 18545.33, 
    5779.33, 28780, 31800, 10460.67, 14330.67, 16945.33, 14323.33, 
    12078.67, 17226.67, 19428.67, 25380, 9596.67, 10008, 10206.67, 
    9514.67, 8998.67, 9454, 12915.33, 13706.67, 5633.33, 6972.67, 
    6780, 9155.33, 9674, 13180.67, 10200, 9502, 10344.67, 10446, 
    14296.67, 14274.67, 12012.67, 11167.33, 24953.33, 24980, 
    10092, 9101.33, 12308.67, 13586, 11862, 12034, 22446.67, 
    25173.33)), row.names = c(NA, -640L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada na função `reshape2::dcast`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando o [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse), você primeiro precisa criar um [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame) intermediário agregando os valores de `LUX` e depois espalhar ele (`spread()`):

```
library(tidyverse)

dados %>% 
  group_by(AVA, FAT1, FAT2) %>% 
  summarise(LUX = sum(LUX)) %>% 
  spread(FAT2, LUX)

# Groups:   AVA, FAT1 [16]
   AVA               FAT1   Banana Gliricídia    Ingá Pupunha Solteiro
   <ord>             <fct>   <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Março de 2016     Antes 182723.     60839.  58870. 380707.  381637.
 2 Março de 2016     Após   37848.     20230.  82552. 255576   269647.
 3 Agosto de 2016    Antes  30737      42974   24698. 300354   183517 
 4 Agosto de 2016    Após   69323.    177468.  97595. 206848.  216887.
 5 Dezembro de 2016  Antes  77501.    101928  163812  118205.  211391.
 6 Dezembro de 2016  Após  256707.    156195. 220407. 385241.  460753.
 7 Março de 2017     Antes  34390      34405  114098  106540.  285535 
 8 Março de 2017     Após   40180      81225   69370   92315   126330 
 9 Agosto de 2017    Antes  20225      26085   18355   35565    42315 
10 Agosto de 2017    Após   48835     108410   64755  100785   109135 
11 Fevereiro de 2018 Antes 143355      34405  148573. 109725   285535 
12 Fevereiro de 2018 Após   51844.     83628   59205.  96237.  102267.
13 Abril de 2018     Antes  51885.     72475.  63535.  96642.  105253.
14 Abril de 2018     Após   37446.     51785.  43426   65078.   67081.
15 Agosto de 2018    Antes  38343.     96392.  63485. 131195.  330319.
16 Agosto de 2018    Após   71098     122475.  84401. 116604   130174.
```

A tabela intermediária só precisou ser criada porque havia mais de uma linha para cada conjunto de `AVA` + `FAT1`. Caso as informações já fossem únicas para cada grupo, bastaria usar o `spread()`.

Comment: Que solução elegante. Gostei mais do que a solução que utiliza `reshape2::dcast`.

Comment: Grato pela dica Tomás Barcellos e Marcus Nunes!!!

Comment: estou utilizando `base %>% pivot_longer(cols=all_of(c("FAT1","FAT2")),names_to = "variable",values_to = "value") %>% group_by(FAT1, FAT2) ` , e estou encontrando dificuldades ao usar `summarise(soma = sum(value))`, aparentimente ele não soma, se uso `mean()`, `sd()` fica ok, agora se uso `sum()`, ele só repete os valores. alguém sabe me dizer o porque?

Comment: Não consegui entender. Recomendo fazer outra perguntar e garantir a reprodutibilidade do exemplo/problema.

Answer (score 3):

Por primeiro, você precisa criar uma variável identificadora:

```
dados$id <- 1:nrow(dados)
```

Em seguida, as variáveis que você quer que fique na linha precisam estar no lado esquerdo da formula, e na coluna do direito. Por fim, tu precisa falar qual função você quer agregar os dados. Neses caso, coloquei `sum`, que não fará nenhuma diferença, apenas irá manter os dados originais (pois você tem apenas 1 valor) para cada combinação:

```
reshape2::dcast(dados, id + AVA + FAT1 ~ FAT2, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "LUX")
     id               AVA  FAT1   Banana Gliricídia     Ingá   Pupunha  Solteiro
1     1     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00     0.00      0.00  39018.33
2     2     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00     0.00      0.00  38870.00
3     3     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00     0.00      0.00  40375.00
4     4     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00     0.00      0.00  39686.67
5     5     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00     0.00      0.00  53363.33
6     6     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00     0.00      0.00  55666.67
7     7     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00     0.00      0.00  56888.33
8     8     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00     0.00      0.00  57768.33
9     9     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00  5029.33      0.00      0.00
10   10     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00  4758.00      0.00      0.00
11   11     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00  4810.67      0.00      0.00
12   12     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00  5044.67      0.00      0.00
13   13     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00 17840.67      0.00      0.00
14   14     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00  2917.33      0.00      0.00
15   15     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00  8508.67      0.00      0.00
16   16     Março de 2016 Antes     0.00       0.00  9960.67      0.00      0.00
```

No entanto, se você quiser agregar os dados, basta:

```
reshape2::dcast(dados[, -5], AVA + FAT1 ~ FAT2, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "LUX")

                 AVA  FAT1    Banana Gliricídia      Ingá   Pupunha  Solteiro
1      Março de 2016 Antes 182722.66   60839.33  58870.01 380706.67 381636.66
2      Março de 2016  Após  37847.99   20229.93  82551.81 255576.00 269646.67
3     Agosto de 2016 Antes  30737.00   42974.00  24697.80 300354.00 183517.00
4     Agosto de 2016  Após  69323.33  177468.22  97594.67 206847.82 216886.68
5   Dezembro de 2016 Antes  77500.66  101928.00 163812.00 118205.34 211390.67
6   Dezembro de 2016  Após 256707.32  156195.33 220407.33 385240.67 460753.33
7      Março de 2017 Antes  34390.00   34405.00 114098.00 106540.33 285535.00
8      Março de 2017  Após  40180.00   81225.00  69370.00  92315.00 126330.00
9     Agosto de 2017 Antes  20225.00   26085.00  18355.00  35565.00  42315.00
10    Agosto de 2017  Após  48835.00  108410.00  64755.00 100785.00 109135.00
11 Fevereiro de 2018 Antes 143355.00   34405.00 148573.33 109725.00 285535.00
12 Fevereiro de 2018  Após  51843.99   83628.00  59205.34  96237.33 102267.35
13     Abril de 2018 Antes  51885.33   72475.33  63535.34  96642.01 105252.68
14     Abril de 2018  Após  37445.99   51784.69  43426.00  65078.01  67080.67
15    Agosto de 2018 Antes  38343.33   96391.66  63484.67 131195.32 330319.32
16    Agosto de 2018  Após  71098.00  122475.34  84400.68 116604.00 130174.01
```

aí sim ele retorna o data.frame com a soma de cada uma das espécies de `FAT2` para o valor de `LUX`.